# Regular expression to extract characters in between other characters

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a string which is `//{characters}\n`.

And I need a regular expression to extract the character in between `//` and `\n`.

Comment: @BaliC Regex.Match(numbers, @"\/\w+\\n").Groups[1].Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using RegEx:

```
Regex g;
Match m;
g = new Regex("//(.*)\n");  // if you have just alphabet characters replace .* with \w*
m = g.Match(input);
if (m.Success == true)
    output = m.Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: I have tried the above regex with //;\n1;2. And expected output is ; which is inbetween // and \n. But Match is not finding.

Comment: Once more thing - if you are sure that the input begins with // you should use "^//(.*)\n". And remember that RegEx will match input string "//one\ntwo\n" like "one\ntwo"

Comment: Hello Mist
regex = new Regex(@"([)?(.*)(])?");
            match = regex.Match(delimiter);
            while (match.Success)
            {
                delimiters.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);
                match = match.NextMatch();
            }
Trying to extract characters from [*][&][%] to a list which contains *,&,%.
And the input could be * & % also and expecting the same output.
Can you help me in doing the same.

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions are nice and all, but why not use Substring?

```
string input = "//{characters}\n";
string result = input.Split('\n')[0].Substring(2);
```

or

```
string result = input.Substring(2, input.Length - 3);
```

Comment: Yea..we can do string operations, but that is my last option to go for.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
string s1 =  "//{characters}\n";
string final =  (s1.Replace("//", "").Replace("\n", ""));
```